# Emacs: check for no-window-system in .emacs

Tags: emacs

is it possible, to check if emacs is running in `--no-window-system` (`-nw`) mode within the dot-emacs file (`.emacs`)? I would like to enable/include certain extension only if emacs is in window mode (/or not).

Kind regards,
mefiX

Comment: Similar on emacs stackexchange: [Is there a way to detect that emacs is running in a terminal?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/is-there-a-way-to-detect-that-emacs-is-running-in-a-terminal)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The variable `window-system` is `nil` if the selected frame is on a text-only terminal.

Comment: I used `(when window-system ... stuff ...)` to evaluate all the stuff I want only in window mode.

Comment: Note that the value of `window-system` is specific to the current frame; if you start Emacs in GUI mode then `window-system` will be `t`, but if you connect to that *same* Emacs instance using `emacsclient -t` from a terminal, then `window-system` will be `nil` within that terminal frame. For this reason, it's not good practice to make decisions in `.emacs` based on `window-system` -- instead, embed the corresponding conditional code in hook or other functions that will be called later.

Comment: I've never used emacsclient before. Honestly, I don't even know what it is or what it does. So evaluating window-system works fine for me ... at least by now. However, thank you very much for that hint!

Answer (score 10):

Put the code you want to run when emacs executes in a windowed environment inside a when block and use the display-graphic-p predicate i.e.

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (do something)
  (do-another-thing))
```

or reverse

Comment: According to the manual this answer represents best practice see last sentence on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html

Comment: not for lisp-newbies like me : you don't have to write 'do'